# Backbone checkbox value in tr view

Tags: jquery, checkbox, backbone.js, collections, html-table

I'm currently programming the web interface for a MVC web application and I need to get the models which have their checkbox checked.

At the moment this is the template I use to generate a single table row:

```
<td><span class="userintern"><%= intern %></span></td>
<td><span class="username"><%= name %></span></td>
<td><input id="add" class="add" type="checkbox" ></td>
```

This is the code for the view of the table row:

```
var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    template: _.template(messageuser),
    initialize: function () {
    },
    events: {
        'click .add': 'add'
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        $('.add').prop('checked', false);
        return this;
    },
    add: function () {
        console.log($('.add').prop('checked'));
        if($('.add').prop('checked'))
            common.vent.trigger('messageView:add_user', { model: this.model });
        else
            common.vent.trigger('messageView:remove_user', { model: this.model });
    }
});

return UserView;
```

My problem is, the first checkbox works perfectly fine, gives me true/false based on the status of the checkbox. Checkbox 2 -> ... always return false.
I'm suspecting this is because I try to access the `$('.add')` with jQuery which is the same for every checkbox, but how can I do this another way?

Comment: You can check for the checkbox that is a descendent of your view's *el* using `this.$el.find('.add').prop('checked')`. Aside from that you really shouldn't have the *id* attribute in your template since the *id* should be unique.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for! Stupid of me to forget about the $el property...

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help. I've added it as an answer so you can mark your question as answered.

Comment: Yes, just approved your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for an element that is a child of your view's `el` by performing a search [scoped to your view](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) for example

```
 this.$('.add').prop('checked'); //equivalent to running: `this.$el.find(selector)`
```

Comment: Looks like I forgot to upvote the answer on my first question ever :-)